# Set default address in web3?

Tags: web3js, addresses

I've tried to change the value of defaultAccount on web3.min.js from void to an address, but it didn't seem to work and web3.eth.defaultAccount remained undefined when I called it from the console.

How do I preset that variable?

This is what I'm doing:

[image: Defined from]

I believed the from field would've done the trick, but it didn't. So I tried to force the value

[image: change the variable just to make sure]

and then I run `truffle console`

[image: Running on console]

Comment: Please post a screenshot or a console trace how do you do this and how you inspect it did not change? There shouldn't be anything magical about this and it should just work.

Comment: There it is, Mikko

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong as you are not supposed to edit web3.min.js - have you tried to set the variable as shown in the answer below?

Comment: I did it after my attempt to only put the from parameter failed. About the code below: do you mean putting it in truffle.js? I understood I'd have to do it on the console, which I was already doing anyways

Answer (score 2):

`// set the default account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0xWalletAddress';`

Refer to https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#defaultaccount

Comment: I'm aware I can change this while running the console, I just want to save that time and have it pre-defined